# CURDATE() is not working in php query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have strange problem, I executed this query in MySQL database and i get this result.

```
SELECT id,content                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
FROM table 
WHERE id = 3
AND CAST(`date` AS DATE) = CURDATE()
AND `order` = 1;
```

but when i use this query in php file it returns NUll. i used a date like '2015-05-17' and `date()` php function instead of `CURDATE()` but it has no result again.
it works when i remove this condition `CAST(date AS DATE) = CURDATE()`

```
$sql = SELECT id,content                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       FROM table 
       WHERE id = $this->id
       AND CAST(`date` AS DATE) = CURDATE()
       AND `order` = $order;

$db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

what is a solution?

Comment: You do not need to `CAST`. `AND `date` = CURDATE()` should be fine. In addition, you should not use 'date' as the name of a column because it is a MySQL reserved word: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: use NOW() instead of CURDATE()

Comment: The OP doesn't want the timestamp @BrijalSavaliya and the `CAST` would still fail.

Comment: i have used "CAST(`date` AS DATE) = CURDATE()" its working for me ? can you tell me your field "Type" @h3dgh

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya it's type was DATE and i changed it to timestamp. my query works in mysql with two types but it has no result in php file.

Comment: Do you have any PHP errors? Have you looked in the error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes , I checked it and there is not any error.